# Recruiter asking for help understanding JEE5 or JEE6 and J2EE. (NOT A JOB POSTING NOT LOOKING FOR CANDIDATES)

Tags: java-ee

I am a recruiter. I want to learn as much as I can about JEE5/JEE6 so when I try and find these types of candidates I can at least talk intelligently with them.

What I need to understand is what goes without saying?
So for example, if you were a J2EE or had experience with JEE5 or JEE6, could I assume you had spring and hibernate? Could I assume you had Jboss and Jboss admin?

I guess it would be helpful if I posted a job description and let you guys tell me what is wrong with it?

Candidate must have the following skills:

- Extensive experience with Java/J2EE Development
- Experience with various Development Tools (Eclipse, SVN, etc.)
- Database design and SQL expertise
- Web Services
- JavaServer Faces (JSF)
- Model-View-Controller (MVC)
- Comfortable working in a Unix/Linux environment
- Maven
- JBoss Deployment and Administration
- Swing/AWT
- Scrum/Agile
- TeamForge

So if I was a certified J2EE would i have all these skills? Are these skills even grouped right? If you were writing this job description for a J2EE what would you change? I am trying to learn. I am not posting this to find candidates for a job. I am posting this to try and get a handle on what a hiring manager is asking for and be able to tell him, there is no way a J2EE has all these skills or, no problem, all J2EE's have these skills. Am I making sense?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the job ad as long as it reflects what the employer need. What is your question? Can you focus it a bit more, please?

Comment: Employers always ask for more than they can get.  If I can do the job, I will apply.  The same might not be true of others, however, and you might be turning away some good candidates with a skills list this specific.

Answer (score 2):

A regular JEE developer would know either most of those skills or the equivalent, except for one outlier: Swing/AWT. Those are both desktop application GUI programming, so a typical web developer would most likely not be very familiar with them (in the sense that they wouldn't use it often).

There are a few things on that list with equivalents that you may need to know about when talking to the candidate:

- JavaServer Faces - JavaServer Pages is the biggest contender, otherwise there are other templating languages that can be used - Velocity and FreeMarker are popular options.
- SVN - Git, Mercurial, and CVS are other common version control systems.
- JBoss - Application server. Some other possibilities are Tomcat, Glassfish, and WebLogic.

Overall, nothing about that skill listing is *too* odd. It isn't asking for a skill in a completely unrelated skillset (such as another language or platform entirely).

The issue comes with assuming anything. Hibernate is a *very* common skill, but it can be used in multiple flavors. It is also very complex, so while a developer may know how to use it, they might not know how to set it up or the fine-tuning that could be necessary.

One last thing - JEE5/6 and Spring tend not to be used at the same time. For a long time Spring was how the JEE stack should have been - and then JEE5/6 brought in some of the features. Nowadays they are competing platforms. Nothing stops you from using Spring in a JEE project, but it would be adding redundant capabilities and complexity for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

I will run through the chances that a given software developer applying for a typical Java developer possesses the following skills:

> Extensive experience with Java/J2EE Development
>   Experience with various Development Tools (Eclipse, SVN, etc.)

Goes without saying

> Database design and SQL expertise

Common

> Web Services
>   JavaServer Faces (JSF)
>   Model-View-Controller (MVC)
>   Comfortable working in a Unix/Linux environment
>   Maven

Common for web application developers

> JBoss Deployment and Administration
>   Swing/AWT

Uncommon for web application developers

> Scrum/Agile

Familiarity should be common but I don't think anybody should be discounted for not having worked in an Agile/Scrum environment before.

> TeamForge

This should be a nice to have as this a very specific skill set that probably doesn't have a very high learning curve.